# Where should a question about LaTeX usage go?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions

My first instinct is Superusers, but on the other hand, you could say that writing stuff in LaTeX is programming in a DSL.

But then you have questions about typography, styles, and you have questions like the main reason why im asking this question:

*How do I best cite a piece of software in my thesis?*

Should I wait for superusers or is this stackoverflow stuff?

Comment: See also the later, but more general: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Now there is a new Stack Exchange site dedicated to TeX-related questions (including LaTeX):
[TeX - LaTeX - Stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

While most LaTeX questions would be on topic also on Stack Overflow and/or on SuperUser, they often will be better answered there.

Answer (score 14):

Every document you write in a TeX derived language---*every document*---is a program. TeX and LaTeX are Turing complete, the problem is to get the desired output, and as such these questions are not out of place on StackOverflow (and we already have 200+ questions there, most of which are pretty good).

I've been fighting this battle for a while and simply won't quit.

Personally, however, I do see a distinction between. "I [can't remember|never learned] the command for Foo in LaTeX." on one hand and "My university doesn't provide a dissertation style and I need to achieve Bar obscure [layout result|front-matter arrangement|bibliographic convention]. What do I do?" on the other.

The former might be better on SuperUser, but the later definitely belong on StackOverflow.

Such is my $0.02.

Comment: +1 I think there are much more people on stackoverflow than superuser that can help with TeX problems, because TeX (and Metafont...)  is largely programming.

Answer (score 0):

Although the distinction between "using" and "programming" L<sub>a</sub>T<sup>e</sup>X is fuzzy, I would definitely say that, on the whole, the questions should go on SuperUser. Although your question is about citing code, it's not strictly about programming, so I would go with SU personally.

Comment: I accepted your answer and took your advice: http://superuser.com/questions/8743/how-to-cite-software-in-latex

Comment: If anyone gives you a hard time, send them to me ;-)