# Lyx is not Latex

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, superuser, latex

I agree with the general principle that writing a [latex document is writing in a markup language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stackoverflow) that often insists on receiving the respect due to a programming language.

I'm less happy to see the use of tools, such as LyX, appearing on SO in this way, where the [question doesn't actually involve latex source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184030/list-of-figures-does-not-look-good-number-and-text-on-top-of-each-other).

Does it make sense to say these are SU questions, or does this just make matters needlessly complex?

Comment: What does Cf. mean?

Comment: Cf. = In reference to. Look over here. Remember this? So, as we were talking... @dow

Comment: @Downvot: FTFY!

Comment: Wtf does FTFY mean?

Comment: WTF does Wtf mean, @dow?

Comment: http://www.google.com.ar/search?q=FTFY&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.gentoo:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a

Comment: @joh, http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wtf

Comment: Seeing how most lyx-questions end up on tex.stackoverflow.com it would be interesting to reevaluate this issue. I too would have expected LyX questions to go to superuser.com, especially after getting a pure-LaTeX answer to an explicit lyx-question, but common usage seems to be to put it on the tex site right now.

Answer (score 4):

IMO LyX questions belong on http://superuser.com just as much as MS Word or OO.o Writer questions.

Questions about editing ODF programaticaly would belong on http://stackoverflow.com, just as a LaTeX question would.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's making things needlessly complex, and can stay on SO.  My reasoning is that if we consider LaTeX to be programming, then tools that are used *specifically* to work with LaTeX can be considered "programming tools" and are fair game, just like IDEs, markup validators, and debuggers.

It can probably be considered to be similar to Dreamweaver.  Technical questions belong on SO, for example regarding generating specific markup codes or proper encoding.  General usage questions, e.g. "Why does Dreamweaver crash after my upgrade?" belong on SU.

Comment: LyX is a Text Processor that happens to use LaTeX as it's backend. SO material in my opinion.

Comment: @The Big Cheese: You mean SU? ;) ... Fair enough, like I said I don't know anything about it.

Comment: yeah, SU. Must. get. coffe.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this simply comes down to the question of **Which site has the most people able to answer this question**, and the answer is the same site as the one with the most LaTeX users.

That said, why do LaTeX questions belong on StackOverflow?  Although LaTeX could kind of be considered programming in some sense, in reality it's not programmers who use LaTex, and so its not programmers who are best suited to answer LaTeX questions.

Comment: LaTeX is used by some of us as a templating system for reports.

Comment: Lyx questions that don't involve Latex source attract much less interest on SO than regular Latex qns, and without the latex regulars participating.  This might be a case for treating the cases differently.

Comment: *"why do LaTeX questions belong on StackOverflow?"* See my answer to the question the OP linked: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stackoverflow/12926#12926