# Migrating questions to TeX/LaTeX site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can SO questions on TeX be migrated to tex.SX?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70466/can-so-questions-on-tex-be-migrated-to-tex-sx)

StackOverflow currently has 1,713 questions tagged "latex".  Most (not all!) of these would be much better-served on tex.stackexchange.com, but many of them were asked before it existed, and the existing collection tends to draw more similar questions.

Is there a way to migrate these questions to the appropriate site?  I note that the "close" dialog box doesn't contain the TeX site as one of the "this belongs on" options for "off-topic".