# What's going to happen to a tag on Stack Overflow when another Stack Exchange site covers it?

Tags: discussion, tags, stack-exchange

What's going to happen to a tag on Stack Overflow when another Stack Exchange site covers it?

For instance, there is the [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) site which overlaps with Stack Overflow's [security](/questions/tagged/security) tag.   What's going to happen to Stack Overflow's [security](/questions/tagged/security) tag when Security.SE gets larger and moves out of beta?

Comment: See [this MSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70466/can-so-questions-on-tex-be-migrated-to-tex-sx) for information on how we handled this with TeX/LaTeX; however, bear in mind that the amount of overlap between sites could affect the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not very much will change with the existing questions on Stack Overflow.  New programming questions that are security related can continue to be asked on SO.  Other new questions related to security but that are *not* explicitly about programming should be asked on the IT Security site.

Comment: Sounds perfect, and agrees with what we are hoping for over on security SE. We wouldn't want to have hundreds of old questions dropped on us, but new questions in information and IT security are definitely welcome. Similarly, if we get ones that are really programming questions, we tend to punt them back this way :-)