# Add “belongs on tex.sx” close reason

Tags: feature-request, migration, migration-path-request

> **Related:**
>   [Can SO questions on TeX be migrated to tex.SX?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70466/can-so-questions-on-tex-be-migrated-to-tex-sx)

There’s a steady trickle of LaTeX related questions on Stack Overflow which I always flag so that they can be moved to tex.stackexchange.com. However, this gets old really fast.

I don’t mind flagging them but I don’t think a moderator needs to be concerned with such a routine task. Given that tex.sx is probably here to stay, [I think it’s high time that there is a “belongs on tex.stackexchange.com” close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan/54524#54524).

Comment: @Straitjacket Does this made-up tag really make the question better? For that matter, why was `close-reason` not appropriate?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Closing is for me something different then migrating...and you're requesting a new migration path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposed dupe discusses the relationship between SO and TeX, and doesn't address the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) of adding a migration path, so:

A site is allowed to have 4 migration paths (ok, 5, but one is reserved for the site's meta).  Currently SO has Super User, Programmers, Webmasters, and Server Fault.

In order to add TeX, we would want to see a clear need for it *over* one of the existing paths since it would replace one of the existing paths.

Comment: How hard would it be to allow for more than 4 migration paths?

Comment: I'm surprised at that limit, *particularly* for SO.  Given that it was there first, I'd not be surprised to learn that there are questions asked there that ought to be on loads of the other sites.

Comment: @AndrewStacey a few questions here and there are fine for flagging and mod migration.  It's why mods can migrate anywhere.  Existing as a migration path says that it is a truly common occurrence and is officially blessed.  SO migrates 10+ questions a day to SU and SF.

Comment: Fair enough.  Just feels like more work for the mods than is strictly necessary.