# Why is there a latex tag on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, latex

Why not move all questions with the [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) tag to [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: It looks like a lot of the newer questions that get asked with that tag *do* get migrated there. There's a lot of temporary placeholders that will eventually get auto-deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can SO questions on TeX be migrated to tex.SX?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70466/can-so-questions-on-tex-be-migrated-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would oppose a blanket migration of all question with a LaTeX tag.

The [R statistical programming language](http://www.r-project.org/) includes both [Sweave](http://www.statistik.lmu.de/~leisch/Sweave/) and [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/), which are reproducible research tools that allow for the embedding of R code within a LaTeX document. Questions on these topics regularly come up.

Those of us following the [r] tag often flag those questions to be migrated to [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com) when the answer is likely to involve *only* LaTeX. However, sometimes the solution involves a mix of the two (LaTeX + R code) or just R code.

Also, there are questions within the [r] tag that are about tools for exporting R output into LaTeX, that, again, are purely about the R language. (Like the **xtable** package or some functions in the **HMisc** package.)

Again, we try to be good about migrating questions where the solution will involve only LaTeX, but it is a useful tag to have around (for some).