# Should several year old LaTeX questions on StackOverflow be migrated?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration, latex

Recently I've been seeing a fair number of older (~2010) LaTeX questions in the StackOverflow 10k Review flag queue being flagged for migration to [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

A few examples of some questions I've seen flagged: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3062263/324364), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2944632/324364), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2915092/324364) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4480432/324364).

*New* questions dealing solely with LaTeX I have no problem migrating, but I'm also aware that the community sometimes wishes to treat older questions differently, for a variety of reasons.

For instance, when searching for guidance on this question here on Meta, I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70466/164376) question, where the comments to one of the [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76953/164376) suggests that we should not be blindly migrating old LaTeX questions. However, that question is itself fairly old, and I'm having a difficult time discerning much of a "consensus" out of it.

Now that the migration path to TeX.SE is easier, given its prominent placement in the Off Topic close vote list, I feel like I'm going to see more and more of the existing older LaTeX questions being flagged for migration.

Can I have some stronger guidance on whether I should vote to close + migrate these questions, or should I disagree with the flag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the network has grown and new sites flourished, it's become pretty clear that migrating old content, particularly from SO, can be pretty dangerous. I go over this in detail in [Is “Too old to migrate” a good reason NOT to migrate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136543/166936).

I can't speak for LaTex's community, but a problem I've noticed on UX is that old migrations have problems:

1. They're not representative of our community. The tone is too different, they're just *weird*.
2. Votes are crazy inflated. It seems like every SO question from 08/09 has a score of 40 and it really throws off the scoring of posts. This is especially a problem since, per #1, these migrated posts are usually that good by your site's standards. Those votes aren't representative of your community either.
3. Who cares? The question is long since answered in most cases and the user has probably long since moved on. It's just an artifact.

I tend to reject any migration that's more than a month old unless there are extremely good reasons to accept it. This is also why I, as a Workplace pro temp mod, am not accepting any of Stack Overflow or Programmers' old Workplace related questions.

Comment: Ok. This answer, combined with [this](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/869/6180) question that I was pointed to on the TeX meta site help a lot.