# How to move a question from superuser to stackoverflow?

Tags: support, specific-question, cross-posting

Yesterday on superuser.com I asked a [programmer-productivity question](https://superuser.com/questions/129297/how-to-determine-which-source-files-are-required-for-an-eclipse-run-configuration) about the existence of a feature in the Eclipse IDE.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get a response along the lines of "yes, it exists, here's how" or "no, you can't do that yet". THe question is only one day old, so maybe I'm impatient, but only 7 other users have even looked at the question and the sole answer so far didn't help me.

Eclipse is a programmer's tool, and stackoverflow.com is full of programmers using it. Maybe someone there knows the answer! But I don't want cross-post the question, because as far as I understand, that not how to do things round here.

How do I get my question moved to stackoverflow.com so that more Eclipse users will read my question?

Comment: For information, your question was suited for SU, but you can have better answers on Stack Overflow indeed. I have seen this question when you asked it, I'm myself curious how to do that. Voting to migrate it on SO.

Comment: Remember that just because you're asking about using a specific program doesn't mean it shouldn't be [posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43198/emacs-questions-superuser-or-stackoverflow) on [SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su) originally.  Lots of questions get inappropriately migrated and this is probably why you went to SU first.

Comment: also remember that SU is a bit slower than SO...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just noticed Gnoupi's close vote on this question and migrated it.  For future reference, if you decide you asked a question on the wrong site, you're welcome to flag the question for moderator attention and ask us to migrate it for you.

Comment: Just checked out the migrated question and already I've got a promising answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It will be moved to stackoverflow.com if at least 5 moderators deems that it is appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: s/moderators/3k+ users/