# Inconsistent policy on emacs?

Tags: discussion, migration, policy

A while ago, I asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43198/144964). The answers seemed to suggest that if the question is about *emacs* rather than about lisp coding or whatever, then it should go on superuser. So I had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4269284/219352) that I assumed was about emacs. So I asked it on SU, but within seconds it had been migrated to SO. Someone on SO voted to close the question.

So I think there needs to be a better policy on where these kinds of questions belong, and it needs to be *consistently* applied.

Comment: Well, that's...interesting. Site selection in cases like this is a matter of judgment and obviously not everyone agrees.

Comment: I voted to migrate to SU when I replied to the question on SO. I consider general Emacs questions to be off-topic on SO since they have nothing to do with programming. I agree that a better policy would be nice (if people could be convinced to apply it!) — my impression is that currently many questions are closed on SU just because one of the ♦ moderators (usually Diago) thinks they might get a better response elsewhere (even when they are unambiguously on-topic on SU).

Comment: @Gilles: I think whether a question related to emacs belongs on SO or not depends on the question. For example, I think these pretty clearly do: 1. Programming questions about elisp, 2. Use of emacs as a programming tool. Both of these are clearly on-topic according to the FAQ.

Comment: @Chris I fully agree. That's what I meant by “general Emacs questions”: questions that apply to any Emacs user, not just to programmers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will always be inconsistency for this sort of thing. What you need to remember is that questions aren't closed/migrated by just a few people who can convene, decide on definite policy and stick to it consistently... these actions are taken by people within a vast community, who will have different interpretations of whatever policy is recommended.

Comment: Still it makes sense to strive for consistency.